# Fish shell error

Tags: alpine-linux, fish

When I type command in fish shell, after command it returns: `Could not send own process 401, 'sed' in job 3, 'commandline | sed 's|\s\+|\x1e|g'' from group 400 to group 400 setpgid: unknown error (errno was 1)` but command runs. After some commands fish shell stops responding.  I ran it on *Alpine linux*. How can I fix it? Help please.

Comment: which command or group of command (e.g. `commandline` ) are you using ?

Comment: Any commands, after all commands appears this error. But numbers are different

Comment: have you tried changing `sed 's|\s\+|\x1e|g'` to `sed 's,\s\+,\x1e,g'` ?

Comment: Where must I change it?